# How to assert a property is false at every clock cycle?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

Is there a way to assert whether a already declared property is false at every clock cycle?

For example,

`status[idx]` should be high only if both `req[idx]` and `enable[idx]` is high.

What I would like to have is a negative scenario checker for the above. i.e. the `status` should never go high when either `req` or `enable` is low.

I tried below but vcs gives me below compilation error

```
sequence seq_a (int idx);
  !(req[idx] & enable[idx])
endsequence

sequence seq_b (int idx)
  status[idx] == 1
endsequence

property ppty_ab (int idx)
  disable iff (f_req[idx] & f_enable[idx])
  seq_a(idx) |=> seq_b(idx)
endproperty

generate
  for (idx=0; idx<5; idx++) begin
    a_ab : assert property (@(posedge clk) (not ppty_ab(idx)))
           else $display("ppty_ab [%0d] failed at %t",idx,$time)
  end
endgenerate
```

> Error-[PIWDOAACS] Incorrectly used 'disable iff'
>
> Property instances with 'disable iff' are only allowed in "assert" "assume"   and "cover" statements. Property p_RiseIntDischeck may not be instantiated   in this context.

`seq_a` and `seq_b` is already declared and being used for some other assertion. What is the best/recommended way to **reuse** these sequences and create a negative scenario checker for the above case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the clocking and the `not` into the property itself.

That is:

```
property ppty_ab (int idx)
  @(posedge clk)
  disable iff (f_req[idx] && f_enable[idx])
  not seq_a(idx) ##1 seq_b(idx)
endproperty

generate
  for (idx=0; idx<5; idx++) begin
    a_ab : assert property (ppty_ab(idx))
           else $display("ppty_ab [%0d] failed at %t",idx,$time)
  end
endgenerate
```

Where `not seq_a(idx) ##1 seq_b(idx)` is not the same as `!seq_a(idx) |=> seq_b(idx)`, but the `not` will make the property evaluate to true when the statement is false.

I am assuming that `disable iff` requires that the property is clocked, although I am not sure why.

Comment: Doesn't the above give a different meaning than what's expected? here the property is evaluated when `not seq_a` is true i.e. it checks for `seq_b` whenever `not seq_a` is true. while the actual intent is that `seq_a ` cannot be followed by `seq_b`

Comment: Did you test it?
See under *Handling Asynchronous Resets* in https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/. 
I'll switch `|=>` for `##1` just to be sure.

Comment: you need to use `##1` instead of `|=>`  as  you will get errors stating that property operator usage is not allowed in sequence context.

Answer (score 0):

Your negative property can look like this:

```
property ppty_ab (int idx);
  @ (posedge clk)
  disable iff (f_req[idx] & f_enable[idx])
  !req[idx] | !enable[idx] |=> !status[idx];
endproperty

genvar idx;
generate
  for (idx=0; idx<5; idx++) begin
    a_ab : assert property (ppty_ab(idx))
      else $display("ppty_ab [%0d] failed at %t",idx,$time);
  end
endgenerate
```

Comment: The question is specific about a way to reuse the already declared sequences.